# Expo Firebase Auth Persistence Not Working As Expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I have a `firebaseConfig.js` that looks like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native";
import { AsyncStorage } from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const authState = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});

export const auth = authState;

export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Then, when I sign in the user, it looks like this:

```
import { auth } from "../../firebaseConfig";
...
 signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.trim(), password)
  .then(() => {
     // Handle success.
  })
```

Then in App.js, I have this:

```
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./firebaseConfig";

... 

 onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
  if (user) {
    ...
  } else {
    console.log("No user");
  }
});
```

Each time I refresh the app, I'm getting no user returned from `onAuthStateChanged`. It successfully detects the user after logging in or registering, but not after refreshing the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Luke, onAuthStateChanged does exactly as it says on the tin and what you are experiencing: notifying you of changes after login or logout. If you are already logged in and refresh the page, there won't be any changes in the auth state, hence no notifications. What you are looking for is likely to be the getAuth().currentUser: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user that will retrieve the current logged in user.

Comment: @Stf_F, this does not work. Is it working on your side on React Native / Expo using that strategy? currentUser is always undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by using the latest firebase version, which is currently V10. It handles persistence like you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is your case, but I had the same issue and notice that every time I run the application it uses a different tcp/port son I assume the browser consider it as new site, I set the following into the launch.json file and that solve the issue.
"args": ["-d", "chrome", "--web-port=40000"]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem creating the auth in expo, I solved it by installing the dependency directly from npm and not installing it from expo, the explanation would be the following:

```
Instead of running in your terminal:
npx expo install firebase

Execute:
npm install --save firebase@latest
```

The difference is that when executing the last command the dependency is installed directly from **'npmjs.com'** and not from **'expo.dev'**, apparently the error comes from the expo dependency, I'm not sure about it, that would be the solution for you problem, with respect to your code it does not have any problem you can improve it using a `useState()` if in that case you are going to use a navigation. I hope I've helped :)

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. Is also fixed in v10.